# Verification that $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h) -f(a)}{h}$ are equivalent definitions of the derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

I wanted to verify that for definition of the derivative it is true that:

> $$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h) -f(a)}{h}$$

If I denote $h=x-a$,  we can  let $x\to a$, this means that $h \to 0$. Also notice that $f(x)=f(a+h)$
$$ \lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
As desired.

**Is the main idea here really just to use a variable substitution?**

I suppose there is some formal theorem I also use here that when $f(x) \to y$  we can let $g(f(x)) \to g(y)$ if the function $g$ is continuous.

Comment: On the R.H.S. you want $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$
You can't have $x$ be an varying on one side, and have a definite value on the other.

Comment: What is your question exactly? You started from asking if something is true and you ended up seeking a functional theorem

Comment: I seek a better understanding of this alternative definition, the book just says it is an easy exercise to rewrite it, thus left as a check for the reader , but I don't feel this is very "proper".

Comment: that makes more sense, then I wouldn't need the multiplication by $-1$, might be an error then.

Comment: So your actual question is if there is a formal way to prove the following equality? $$\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}g(a+h)$$

Comment: Either that, or if there is a different approach to my method OR if there is some handy theorem from which this follows instantly? like a limit substitution rule of some kind? - or in short: how do I make this formal.

Comment: It's sort of a question like "can I just do this, or am I making assumptions that I am not aware of because of a lack of knowledge"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the question is if it is possible to prove the following equality:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}g(a+h)$$

Because in this case you can use: $$g(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

> I suppose there is some formal theorem I also use here ...

If you want to use the formal definition of the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=y$$ means that for every $\epsilon>0$ given we can find a value $\delta>0$ so that the following inequation applies for all $w\in[-\delta,\delta]$: $$|g(\underbrace{a+w}_{"x\to a"})-y|<\epsilon$$

However, because $a+w=a+(0+w)$ this also means that: $$|g(a+\underbrace{(0+w)}_{"h\to 0"})-y|=|g(\underbrace{a+w}_{"x\to a"})-y|<\epsilon$$

This however means that: $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}g(a+h)=y$$ ... because we can also find a value $\delta$ for each given value $\epsilon$ ...

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was seeking, thank you.